# nginx location regex directive doesn't fire

Tags: nginx

I'm trying a simple `location` directive in my nginx config, and it doesn't seem to be working all that well; I want to ensure that all requests to a local css or js file have an expires header, so I added the following to my server block (shown below). Am I missing something? The `movies` location block correctly works (and loads CSS), however it does not have the expires header as expected. I've tried putting the wanted location block inside the `movies` location block to no success.

```
server {
  server_name           www.example.com;

  index  index.php index.html index.htm;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/example.com/access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/example.com/error.log;

  root /var/example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # CSS and Javascript -- this is the added location block
  location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }

  location = /movies {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/movies/;
  }
  location ^~ /movies {
    alias /var/example.com/movies/current/public;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /movies/movies/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~* \.php {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

  ## many other location blocks like the immediate above snipped

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `location ~* \.(css|js)$` block will not match URIs that begin with `/movies`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: `location ^~ /movies` is not a regular expression, it is a prefix location that takes precedence over any regular expression location. Besides, you need URIs that begin with `/movies` to be processed by the `location ^~ /movies` block, as it has a different value for `root`/`alias`. So the correct solution is to use a nested location (and make it work).

Comment: Thanks, @RichardSmith. I'd apparently not nested it correctly somehow; it works correctly now. If you want to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The `location ^~ /movies` block is a **prefix location**, and the `^~` operator causes it to take precedence over **regular expression** locations. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

This is exactly the behaviour you need, because URIs that begin with `/movies` require a different document root to be set.

To define special headers for URIs that begin with `/movies` and end with `.css` or `.js`, use another nested location block.

For example:

```
location ^~ /movies {
    ...
    location ~* \.php {
        ...
    }
    location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
        ...
    }
}
```